# EJB RMI implementation issue

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

RMI specification states that:

> “A method dispatched by the RMI runtime to a remote object
>   implementation (a server) may or may not execute in a separate thread.
>   Calls originating from different clients Virtual Machines will execute
>   in different threads. From the same client machine it is not
>   guaranteed that each method will run in a separate thread”

Now how does EJB, wich uses RMI as a core implementation, deal with this ?

For example If I have a web-app with many threads (one per client HTTP request),
each of them uses the same stateless EJB to issue a request, we would clearly like a server RMI thread per request and of course not like the requests being serialized and served in the same thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get that. This wording is pretty opaque but its occult meaning is that you can't assume it is single-threaded at the server. There are no such implementations of RMI. Concurrent calls from the client will proceed concurrently at the server.

Comment: thanks, am I right to assume that if this would be really the case, it would pose seriuos problems on EJB implementation ?

Comment: Such an implementation would be completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in many implementations of web applications, Enterprise beans are mostly Local, or over-designed and deserve to be local. In the case of local access, calls are shunted, and wont go over RMI. Not saying that this is the case for you, but it is something to consider. However noting that your servlet container and bean container are one and the same, I do not see much use for using remote clients.

The threads managed by your servlet container, and those managed by your enterprise beans container are different. Each will take their own decision on how big their pools are going to be, and what reuse policies are going to be.